# If each is an Enumerable and with_index is an Enumerable, then why can each iterate arrays but not with_index?

Tags: ruby

I think the question is self-explanatory: If `each` is an Enumerable and `with_index` is an Enumerable, then why can `each` iterate arrays but not `with_index`?

I'll provide an example:

```
 alphabet =  [:a, :b, :c]
 => [:a, :b, :c] 
alphabet.each.class
 => Enumerator 
alphabet.each.with_index.class
 => Enumerator 
alphabet.each
 => #<Enumerator: [:a, :b, :c]:each> 
2.1.2 :036 > alphabet.with_index
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_index' for [:a, :b, :c]:Array
```

It seems unintuitive to me that both are Enumerables, yet `each` can respond_to Array but `with_index` cannot. Because of this, I get forgetful when I try to build these Enumerables:

```
alphabet.each.with_index(1).reduce({}) do |acc, (letter,i)|
end
```

Sometimes I make this mistake:

```
alphabet.with_index(1).reduce({}) do |acc, (letter,i)|
end
```

forgetting about the dependency that `with_index` must be chained to `each`.

Comment: `.each` isn't an "enumerable", it's a _method_ that will give you an Enumerator.  You can call `.with_index` on an Enumerator that will also return an Enumerator, but `.with_index` isn't defined on the Array class.

Comment: Yup your premise and accompanying terminology is wrong, so kinda makes this question unanswerable. `Enumerable` and `Enumerator` are two different things. The former is a module, the latter is a class. Both can define methods, but these methods are never referred to by the class in which they're defined. So you don't call a method defined in Object as an Object.

Comment: This video on Enumerable and Comparable was helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cs-mAtWRjCg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) module**

All methods in the module `Enumerable` are instance methods that require their receiver to be an enumerator (an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html)). All classes that include the module `Enumerable` (using [Module#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-include)) must possess an instance method `each`, which returns an enumerator. Three examples for built-in classes are [Arrays#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each), [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) and [Range#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-each).<sup>1</sup> To include `Enumerable` in a custom class, therefore, one must define a method `each` (that returns an enumerator) on that class.

When a method contained in `Enumerable` is executed on an instance of a class that includes `Enumerable`, Ruby inserts the method `each` between the instance and the `Enumerable` method.

For example, you can think of `[1,2,3].map { |n| 2*n } #=> [2,4,6]` as `[1,2,3].each.map { |n| 2*n }` (using `Array#each`), `{ :a = 1, :b => 2 }.map { |k,v| v } #=> [1,2]` as `{ :a = 1, :b => 2 }.each.map { |k,v| v }` (using `Hash#each`) and `(1..4}.map { |n| 2*n } #=> [2,4,6]` as `(1..4}.each.map { |n| 2*n }` (using `Range#each`).

**`with_index`**

Now let's consider the method `with_index`. Which modules (including classes, of course) have an instance method `with_index`?

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select { |m| m.instance_methods.include?(:with_index) }
  #=> [Enumerator::Lazy, Enumerator]
```

(where `Enumerator::Lazy.superclass #=> Enumerator`)
See [ObjectSpace#each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object).

It follows that invoking `with_index` on any class other than these two will raise a *no-method* exception. That includes, for example, `[1,2,3].with_index` and `{ :a=>1 }.with_index`. However, classes that have a method `each` that returns an enumerator can make use of the method [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) by (explicitly) inserting `each` between an instance of the class and `with_index`.

For example<sup>2</sup>,

```
enum = [1,2,3].each.with_index 
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>:with_index>
```

and then perhaps used thusly:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

This works because

```
[1,2,3].each.class
  #=> Enumerator
```

so all instance methods of the class `Enumerator` (including `with_index`) can be invoked on the enumerator `[1,2,3].each`.

<sup>1 A complete list is given by `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select {|k| k.instance_methods.include?(:each)}`.</sup>
<sup>2 One would generally write `enum = [1,2,3].each_with_index` (see [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)) rather than `enum = [1,2,3].each.with_index`, but the latter is sometime used to make use of the fact that `with_index` takes an argument (default 0) that specifies the index base. For example, `[1,2,3].each.with_index(1).to_a #=> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]`.</sup>

Comment: This is a good explanation here: "All methods in the module Enumerable are instance methods that require their receiver to be an enumerator (an instance of the class Enumerator). All classes that include the module Enumerable (using Module#include) must possess an instance method each, which returns an enumerator. "

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739628/understanding-comparable-mixin-and-enumerable-mixin

Answer (score 2):

`each` is not an `Enumerable`, it returns an `Enumerator` (pay attention to the spell) which `is_a?(Enumerable)`.

Why `[1,2,3].with_index` doesn't work? Because `with_index` is an instance method of `Enumerator`, not a method of `Enumerable`.

Comment: Yes you are right. with_index is not in the Enumerable method list. This is so confusing. Why is this method not in the Enumerable list?

Comment: Maybe it's just because Matz doesn't like `array.with_index`, or maybe it sounds not like a loop. There is `Enumerable#each_with_index` though.